# how to use particles.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I can't seem to get particles.js working--what exactly am I doing wrong? 
Any insights would be appreciated, I can't determine if the error is due to an external dependency or not...

HTML:

```
<div id = "particles-js"></div>

<!-- particles -->
<script src = "particles.js-master/particles.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
/* ---- particles.js container ---- */

#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #3284BF;
  background-image: url('');
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Javascript:

```
/* particlesJS.load(@dom-id, @path-json, @callback (optional)); */
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'particles.js-master/particles.json', function() {
  console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

JSON

```
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 100,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 1500
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffb300"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 1,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3.945738208161363,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 3,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 1200,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 200,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}
```

Comment: does the script get loaded?

Comment: Yup, to the best of my understanding it has

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved--I needed to make a separate javascript file called app.js and put the JSON in that as a JS function (see how they did their demo and fiddle around with it till you can make it do what you want)